# Elm form - show validation error only after leaving the field and no input was entered - dirty/visited

Tags: elm

I would like to show validation error only when field was visited but no valued is entered.

I know there are:

- https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-validate
- http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/ericgj/elm-validation/1.0.1/Validation
- https://github.com/etaque/elm-form

  but can't figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `blur` event:

```
input [ on "blur" (Json.Decode.map FieldBlurred targetValue) ] []
```

This assumes a Msg constructor like this, which will receive the text of the text box on blur:

```
type Msg
   = ...
   | FieldBlurred String
```

Then in your update, handle the empty string appropriately:

```
case msg of
    FieldBlurred "" -> ...  -- invalid! 
    FieldBlurred val -> ... -- ok
```